# Atmel-ICE got burned. Need identification of IC marked: BYJ 42J P5D0

Tags: identification, atmel, atmel-ice

I managed to burn my ATMEL-ICE by connecting 24V to GND on my PCB, while the ICE was connected to it.

Now, I found that this IC (P5D0) gets really hot as soon as I connect the USB to the ICE:

[image: P5D0]

But I do not know what its name is. Googling P5D0 / BYJ 42J P5D0 does not pop up ICs.

It's this chip on the upper right corner:

[image: Atmel-ICE open]

Any ideas what IC it is? (I think it's a step-down regulator because of all the capacitors on its side and the coil -I think-)

Comment: The fact that is gets hot and not shorts your USB power supply probably means it goes into thermal shutdown and something after this regulator is shorted. My best guess is one of those logic translation ic's.

Comment: I just tested this. I injected 1.5V 3A max to a cap after the IC (the cap was measuring 0.8 ohms) and the only think that got heated was the IC, so I think its the IC again. (I can see whats heating up by placing isopropanol on the pcb. If something heats up, the isopropanol evaporates on that spot)

Comment: judging by it's neighbours it looks like some sort of switch mode regulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the *TPS62240DRV*, which is a step down DC/DC converter. It comes in a WSON package, which looks like the one in the picture. The BYJ marking is also visible in the datasheet (TPS6224x from Texas Instruments)

Comment: I was just about to post an answer saying the very same thing :)

Comment: Looks like you are right. When I get the IC and test it Ill post results.